# Blank final variables

Tags: java, int, final

I'm trying to combine

1. public access to variable
2. non static variable
3. not predifined value
4. one time set value (final)
5. int or Integer

**Updated code** is not working and the answer on 'how to do it' must be pretty simple, but I need help:

```
public class foo
{
    public final int smth; //Variable might not have been initialized
    public final Integer smthElse; //Variable might not have been initialized

    public foo(JSONObject myObj)
    {
        if(myObj != null) {
            try {
                int extraParam = Integer.parseInt("ABCD"); //This is just an example for Exception to be called
                smth = extraParam;
                smthElse = extraParam;
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        } else {
            smth = 1;
            smthElse = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I don't want to use (private int + public getter + private setter)

Comment: Your code compiles fine. You're probably not shwing us your real code.

Comment: Now the error is clear: what if myObj is null? Do you initialize the fields in that case? No. Hence the error messages, elling exactly that.

Comment: @JBNizet I have edited the code. I suppose that "if" is the answer for "Variable might not have been initialized". How can I do check final int in last lines of my code to set default values, if I cannot compare it to anything?

Comment: Add an else statement whee you set the default values

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names always start with uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform an assignment within a `try` block, the compiler treats it as “may or may not have happened” after the `try … catch …` construct, which makes it ineligible for `final` variables you want to use after that construct.

The solution is to use temporary non-final variables which you can assign multiple times and perform a definite assignment of the `final` variables at the end of the operation.

E.g.

```
public class Foo
{
    public final int smth;
    public final Integer smthElse;

    public Foo(JSONObject myObj) {
        int smthValue = 1;
        Integer smthElseValue = 2;

        if(myObj != null) try {
            int extraParam = Integer.parseInt("ABCD"); //This is just an example
            smthValue = extraParam;
            smthElseValue = extraParam;
        } catch (Exception e) {}

        smth = smthValue;
        smthElse = smthElseValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When `myObj` is null the final fields won't be set. This results in compilation error, they must be set after `foo(Object myObj, int extraParam)` constructor finishes.

If you need to create an instance of `foo` could add an `else` block.

```
public foo(Object myObj, int extraParam) {
  if (myObj != null) {
    smth = extraParam;
    smthElse = extraParam;
  } else {
    smth = 0;
    smthElse = 0;
  }
}
```

or create a factory method to perform the check.

```
private foo(int extraParam) {
  smth = extraParam;
  smthElse = extraParam;
}

public static foo from(Object myObj, int extraParam) {
  return (myObj == null) ? new foo(0) : new foo(extraParam);
}
```

Comment: I really need to get the instance of this class, but if the class can not check the values itself, the class is lame. The idea is to set final values anyway, even if everything is wrong. And it can go wrong in try{}catch in constructor of class, so I have to write last check (if(smth == null) { //set final int to default value }) ... But 'smth' can not be compared to null ! Seems like it is dead end.

Comment: @AlexShiganov I've update the answer to meet your requirement but it feels more like a use case for `Optional<foo>` from this simple example that you provided.

Comment: I have updated my example code to show unpredictability. Actually I do use JSON, XML, threads, so many kinds of Exceptions may arrise, but in my example code I call it myself.

Comment: @AlexShiganov stop posting different code all the time, it's counter productive. This time the fault lies in `catch (Exception e) {}`. The empty `{}` is a path during which fields won't be set.

Comment: Sorry for that, I thought so many details won't be necessary and the decision could be found quickly... Even if I do try to set 'smth' in catch block, the code will not compile. Currently I see that try{} is the killer of final variable concept for my case.

Comment: @AlexShiganov your `foo` class has to many responsibilities, if it's a POJO it should n't have to do the input parsing. There is nothing wrong with `final` fields but you seem to be coding a [God Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).